# must_not not working for nested elastic query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question.
Suppose there are 2 transactions for the same customer id '11'.In one transaction customer bought 'CLEANSING' product and in second transaction customer bought 'SKIN CARE' product.Now I wanted to filter out customers who bought product 'CLEANSING' but not 'SKIN CARE'.But when I try to aggregate by customer id '11' I get the customer because in the 1st transaction he did not purchase product 'SKIN CARE'.How to make elastic look for the entire transactions of a customer and not a single transaction.Please help me out.

These are the transactions -

```
  {
              "transactionId" : "1211",
              "CDID" : "11",
              "transactionDate" : "2019-06-24T09:35:30.2117315Z",
              "lineItems" : [
                {
                  "description" : "BUBBLE BUBBLE MILD FOAMING CLEANSER",
                  "markdownFlag" : "N",
                  "quantity" : 1,
                  "rate" : 14,
                  "value" : 14,
                  "discount" : 0,
                  "amount" : 13.33,
                  "grossAmount" : 14,
                  "itemDetails" : {
                    "itemName" : "BUBBLE BUBBLE MILD FOAMING CLEANSER",
                    "retailDepartmentName" : "CLEANSING",
                  }
                }
              ]
    }

    {
              "transactionId" : "1232",
              "CDID" : "11",
              "transactionDate" : "2019-06-24T09:35:30.2117315Z",
              "lineItems" : [
                {
                  "description" : "BUBBLE BUBBLE MILD FOAMING CLEANSER",
                  "markdownFlag" : "N",
                  "quantity" : 1,
                  "rate" : 14,
                  "value" : 14,
                  "discount" : 0,
                  "amount" : 13.33,
                  "grossAmount" : 14,
                  "itemDetails" : {
                    "itemName" : "BUBBLE BUBBLE MILD FOAMING CLEANSER",
                    "retailDepartmentName" : "SKIN CARE",
                  }
                }
              ]
    }
```

- lineItems is of nested type
- The transactions are made by the same customer
- I am trying to get the customer who bought 'CLEANSING' but did not buy 'SKIN CARE'.I should get no results.

My query -

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "CDID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CDID.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "lineItems1": {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "lineItems",
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must_not": [
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "lineItems.itemDetails.retailDepartmentName.keyword": "SKIN CARE"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "lineItems.itemDetails.retailDepartmentName.keyword": "CLEANSING"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "nested_path": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "lineItems"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "sum1": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "lineItems.quantity"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result -

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "CDID" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "11",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "lineItems1" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "nested_path" : {
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "sum1" : {
                "value" : 1.0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**-Still didn't find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Below Query you can achieve the result.

Mapping Query:

```
PUT /<index_name>
{
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "transactionId": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "CDID": {
              "type": "text"
            },
             "transactionDate": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "lineItems" : {
                "type" : "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Data Mapping:

```
POST /<index_name>/_doc
{
  "transactionId": "1211",
  "CDID": "11",
  "transactionDate": "2019-06-24T09:35:30.2117315Z",
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "description": "BUBBLE BUBBLE MILD FOAMING CLEANSER",
      "markdownFlag": "N",
      "quantity": 1,
      "rate": 14,
      "value": 14,
      "discount": 0,
      "amount": 13.33,
      "grossAmount": 14,
      "itemDetails": {
        "itemName": "BUBBLE BUBBLE MILD FOAMING CLEANSER",
        "retailDepartmentName": "CLEANSING"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Search Query:

```
GET /test_trans/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "lineItems",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "lineItems.itemDetails.retailDepartmentName": "CLEANSING"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match": {
                "lineItems.itemDetails.retailDepartmentName": "SKIN CARE"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "avg"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "nested_path": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "lineItems"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum1": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "lineItems.quantity"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't get the question.Your query will just give me the results of customers who bought SKIN CARE whereas he wants something different.

Comment: Yes exactly @rahul

Comment: now i changed the query.The query will return the  customer who bought 'CLEANSING' but did not buy 'SKIN CARE'.

Comment: @dhamo I want by customer so I should aggreagte it with CDID.Even if I do that it gives me the customer because it is looking by transaction.Because in one transaction he has not purchased 'SKIN CARE' .Try ingesting one transaction for the same customer who bought 'SKIN CARE' and then try again.You got the result because you had only one transaction.